# Hosting my project with XAMPP broke my MVC structure

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller, xampp

I used to call a method from my controller to be redirected to an other view, when I was in the index view like this :

```
<a class=link_to_show href="/new">Go to other view</a>
```

this would call the method from my Controller:

```
public function new(): void
    {
        $this->view->setFile("new");
        $this->view->render();
    }
```

This used to work when I hosted my project with **DDEV** but now it is not working and I am getting a "**Not Found**" Error when I am clicking on the link. I am still a beginner and I dont know why it is not working anymore, since I am hosting my project with **XAMPP**. I also did not quite understand, how a method from the controller is being called like that "**/new**"

Comment: is it a "Not Found" from your app or one from default Apache server? Sounds like you not setup .htaccess for rewrites

Comment: It is from Apache server

Comment: Okay, have you setup .htaccess for rewrites?

Comment: No, I dont know where this file is located, I am searching now and trying to do that

Comment: " I also did not quite understand, how a method from the controller is being called like that "/new"" are you using a framework of some kind like laravel or code igniter'?

Comment: No, I am not using laravel or code igniter

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with ddev, so I'm removing the ddev tag.

Comment: In xampp the link `/new` is looking for the file path `htdocs/new`  I guess your project is in a dir inside htdocs? So the path would be `htdocs/my-project/new` (in your link remove the htdocs part) .  But also, you've not got a file extension so there is something managing your routing taking care of clean urls (or was on your old system I guess)